# Atajo de teclado para un script ejecutable en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Tengo una ejecutable alojado en mi escritorio, y me crear gustaría un atajo de excritorio para abrirlo, pero no sé como hacerlo? sí estuviera en el directorio donde se encuentra el ejecutable podría escribir dentro de la terminal `./file`
pero quiero crear un atajo de escrito como el que existe en la terminal (Alt + ctrl + t) para abrirlo sin recurrir a la terminal, estoy usando ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes como crear un atajo personalizado:

https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/ubuntu/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-ubuntu-16-04/

Lo único que tienes que hacer es colocar el fichero ejecutable (acuérdate de darle permisos de ejecución) en tu directorio `home`.

De esta manera para el atajo el comando que tienes que poner es `~/.file` donde `~` hace referencia a tu home.

Si tienes problemas ponlo en los comentarios y lo miramos.

Un saludo